# How to determine the irreducible characters for $S_n$

Tags: symmetric-groups, characters

Is there a certain way one can determine the irreducible characters for $S_n$?

I am trying to find all the irreducible characters for $S_4$ and $S_5$, but I have no idea how to go about this or where to start.

Comment: For starters, what is an irreducible character?

Comment: The best way to answer your question is to consult reliable reference sources that already have the answer. For example, try [Group Character Table Database](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~mschaps/DATA/database.html).

Comment: Lots of textbooks on representation theory should have the answer, which involves computations on Young tableaux.